# error in javascript file while there is no error

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

I started to work with JS and brackets, I have this simple JS code in file called `scan.js`:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", function (event) {
        let output = document.getElementById("txtPath");
        let files = event.target.files;
        alert(files[0].name)
    }, false);
}
```

But brackets shows the error:

> ERROR: Parsing Error: Unexpected token output

Image example:

[image]

When I run the page there is no errors at the chrome dev tool and all works as expected.

The html:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scan.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scan.css" />
</head>

<body> 
   <div class="file-upload">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtPath" placeholder="No file selected" />
            <input id="btnBrowse" type="button" value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" />
            <input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file" />
        </div>
        <button id="btnScan">Scan</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you use `var` instead of `let`, does the IDE still show the warning?

Comment: check the js version that's used by your ide, if it's old version, it will not recognize `let`

Comment: I tried to change to `var` instead od `let` and now it shows more errors. like `ERROR: 'window' is not defined`

Comment: How do you run your script? with index.html ? or in the node environment? can you please show all your project structure?

Comment: can you please show your html file?

Comment: @HDallakyan see my edit

Comment: Where do you use your let output - variable?

Comment: it's all just a linter problem, what version of adobe-brackets and eslint are you using?

Comment: @Icepickle Release 1.14 (the new version)